# Loop inside a multidimensional element before post it

Tags: javascript, php

How can I iterate inside elements in JavaScript?

I've those elements:

```
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[7]" value="1">
   <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[7]" value="14">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[4]" value="2">
   <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[5]" value="1">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[4]" value="2">
</div>
```

and this script to edit form before submit:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var form = $(this);   

   // i tried this
   var rows = $(this).find(".row");
   rows.each(function(index, element){
     form.append('<input type="hidden" name="row['+index+'][attributi]['+indexAttr+']" value="' + element.value + '" />');
   });   

  // then submit
  form.submit();

});
```

but I don't know how to retrieve `indexAttr` that in this case is the number inside `attributo[]`, for example, `7` in case of: `attributo[7]`

My goal is to have a structured array in `destination_page.php` like (using my example above):

```
$post = $_POST['row'];

var_dump($post);

// I NEED THIS

row => array(
    0 => array(
       "attributi" => array(
          7 => 1,
          7 => 14
       )
    ),
    1 => array(
       "attributi" => array(
          4 => 2,
          5 => 1
       )
    ),
    2 => array(
       "attributi" => array(
          4 => 2
       )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <div class="row">
     <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[7]" value="1">
     <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[7]" value="14">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[4]" value="2">
     <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[5]" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <input type="text" class="attributo" name="attributo[4]" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button id="save" type="button">save</button>
  </div>
</form>

$("#save").on("click", function(e){

  var form = $("#form");

  // i tried this
  var rows = $(form).find(".row");
  rows.each(function(index, element){
    var input = $(element).find('input');
    input.each(function(i, v){

      var inputValue = $(v).val();
      var inputName = $(v).attr('name');

      var matches = inputName.match(/attributo\[(.*?)\]/);
      var inputIndex = matches[1];

      form.append('<input type="hidden" name="row['+index+'][attributi]['+inputIndex+']" value="' + inputValue + '" />');

    });
  });

  // then submit
  form.submit();

});
```

don't add the hidden fields on submit because it goes into an infinite loop, i've changed your code so it submit when u press the save button i've added to the HTML

also you have a problem in your logic, you can't have an array with the same ID but i'll leave that to you :)

Comment: ops I haven't seen the duplicate ID :) . But this solution I think is ok for my purpose thanks! I'll try it!